# jQuery omits absolute element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with jquery click events. Some background: I want to implement simple scheduler. I have a table (my timetable). When I click on td I want do add a div element (item to schedule in time table. It has position: absolute, can be larger than td!). When I click on this div it should be removed. If td contains a div, I should be able to add another one (they may overlay). The problem is when I try to remove an existing div. An event is called on td element instead of div I've clicked. I checked the target of event and it shows that it was triggered on div element, so now I'm confused... Help, please.
**Edit:** 
Further problem explanation: 
1.I click on a div
2."// td on click" is invoked
3."// remove div" is invoked
4."// add new div" is invoked
I want only "// remove div" to be invoked.

**Edit**
https://jsfiddle.net/rmwfj8Lk/

code:

```
var clickedtd = null;

// add new div
$("#testbutton").click(function () {
    var clientName = $('#clientName').val();
    var eventLength = $('#timeSelect').find(":selected").val();
    var eventPadding = parseInt(clickedtd.css('padding')) * 2;
    var eventHeight = parseInt(clickedtd.css('height'));
    var extraHeight = Math.floor(eventLength) - Math.floor(eventLength - 0.1);
    var eventHeight = eventHeight * eventLength - eventPadding - extraHeight;
    var margin = parseInt(clickedtd.css('height')) / 2 - 1;

    $('<div />', {
        'text': clientName,
        'class': 'floating-event',
        'style': 'height:' + eventHeight + 'px; padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px; margin-top:' + margin + 'px;'
    }).appendTo(clickedtd);
})

// remove div
$("html").on({
    click: function (e) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}, ".floating-event"
);

// td on click
//$("td.visit-cell").on("click", this, function (e) {
//$("td.visit-cell").click(function(e){
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function(e){
    // this shows that div is clicked but event is for td?!?
    console.log("event on:" + e.target)
    clickedtd = $(this);

    // open modal window and set item properties
    $("#modalTrigger").click();

});
```

css:

```
.floating-event {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border: solid 0px #dddddd;
    z-index: 100;
}

.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    overflow:visible;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, it would help a lot to see a working example of the problem, or at the very least your HTML that goes along with this. Can you add a snippet or fiddle showing the behaviour. Secondly, `delegate` was deprecated a long time ago you should use `on()` instead - and also upgrade your version of jQuery

Comment: What is the problem? `.floating-event` receives click event, you remove it, than `td` receives bubbled event and you do `console.log`. What's the problem?

Comment: @Justinas - I updated the problem description. The problem is that `.floating-event` receives click event after `td`. So it's bubbled from `td` to `.floating-event`.

Comment: you need e.stopPropagation in your onclick function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've added my code to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rmwfj8Lk/